# Как починить PHP хостинг после загрузки Django фреймворка?

Tags: php, django, hosting

**Возникла следующая ошибка:**

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
The issue has been logged for investigation. Please try again later.

Technical details for the administrator of this website
This website is powered by Phusion Passenger®, the smart application server built by Phusion®.
```

Данное окно ошибки выдаёт фреймворк Django, однако все сайты работают на php. Тогда вопрос... Как такое получилось, учитывая что загружались до этого лишь файлы на FTP. А изменения, затронули весь сервер глобально.

Судя по всему, здесь есть несколько возможных вариантов:

- Ошибка на уровне оборудования или сети. Возможно, что по какой-то
  причине ваш запрос был перенаправлен на другой сервер, который
  использует Django и Phusion Passenger. Проблемы с настройками
  сервера. Возможно, ваши настройки сервера были неправильно изменены,
  и PHP-сайты теперь обрабатываются сервером, который обычно работает с
  Django. Компрометация безопасности. Если вы уверены, что не делали
  каких-либо изменений, которые могли бы привести к этой проблеме,
  может быть, ваш сервер был взломан. Хакер мог изменить настройки
  сервера или перенаправить трафик.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _Как такое получилось, учитывая что загружались до этого лишь файлы на FTP_, а что и куда грузилось? Возможно затронуты были apache или nginx файлы, которые создают конфликты на сервере